# In what order Bazel links all the files?

Tags: linker, bazel

I know that in general when linker runs in C++, the order of linked arguments in the command matters ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/24675715#24675715)).

In what order does Bazel link files? Does it just go top to bottom of the build file and is there a way to customize it?

Answer (score 1):

Bazel uses 'topological' ordering for linking. From the docs;

> "topological" (formerly "link"): A topological ordering from the root down to the leaves. There is no left-to-right guarantee.

The leaves in this scenario are all your library dependencies as represented as a tree. The linking order is not related to the order the targets are listed in the BUILD file.

You can confirm this by inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/a6d2c623f5ba20910db6b3842fd980f754a1eefa/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/collect/nestedset/Order.java#L37). The docstring from the source code gives a better explanation than the depset docs.

```
 * <p>LINK_ORDER: a variation of left-to-right preorder that enforces topological sorting. In
 * Starlark it is called "topological"; its older deprecated name is "link".
 *
 * <p>For example, for the nested set {A, C, {B, D}}, the iteration order is "A C B D"
 * (parent-first).
 *
 * <p>This type of set would typically be used for artifacts where elements of nested sets go after
 * the direct members of a set, for example when providing a list of libraries to the C++ compiler.
 *
 * <p>The custom ordering has the property that elements of nested sets always come before elements
 * of descendant nested sets. Left-to-right order is preserved if possible, both for items and for
 * references to nested sets.
 *
 * <p>The left-to-right pre-order-like ordering is implemented by running a right-to-left postorder
 * traversal and then reversing the result.
```

There is a way to customise it. Though it is not trivial and involves writing your own starlark plugin.

For example if you where to modify the [my_c_archive.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/main/examples/my_c_archive/my_c_archive.bzl) example adding a different ordering parameter to each call to the depset constructor you could in theory change the order of linking. e.g.
[this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/2f8c04c04462ab83c545ab14c0da68c3b4c96191/examples/my_c_archive/my_c_archive.bzl#L35-L43)

```py
        libraries = depset(direct = [
            cc_common.create_library_to_link(
                actions = ctx.actions,
                feature_configuration = feature_configuration,
                cc_toolchain = cc_toolchain,
                static_library = output_file,
            ),
        ]),
```

Would become this;

```py
        libraries = depset(direct = [
            cc_common.create_library_to_link(
                actions = ctx.actions,
                feature_configuration = feature_configuration,
                cc_toolchain = cc_toolchain,
                static_library = output_file,
            ),
        ],
        # NEW
        order = "preorder"
),
```